# Why does is_front_page and is_home always return true for posts in wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, homepage

My front page is just a list of the posts separated by category. I'm working on a plugin that get the id of the post but needs to test if the user is currently on the front page:

```
if(is_front_page()){
     do this thing
}
else {
     do this other thing
}
```

problem is, on the post pages it returns true for is_front_page. I tried is_home but get the same result.

I have the home in admin set to "latest posts" (not a static page) and displaying the posts on the main page via loop-home. I'm using is_home in the header and getting the correct response.

Comment: Please post your full code in context; include your `settings -> reading` for "front page displays", "front page", and "posts page"; and indicate what template is being used to render the site front page.

Comment: There really isn't any code to post right now as I'm just testing before I dive deeper. As stated, under the settings "Latest Posts" is selected as the front page (default), loop-home.php displays those posts, and post pages use single.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out since the plugin output in the footer I just had to reset the query: wp_reset_query();

Comment: If you need to reset the query, I'll guess you're using `query_posts` somewhere, [which is not recommended](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: Good point. Some of the code for this site was written when I was still a bit green. If I have the time I'll circle back and see where that piece is. Thanks for the heads up.